# Where is the http api for eventstore 3.6?

Tags: eventstoredb

Is there a link to the http endpoints for eventstore 3.6?
I was looking through the documentation provided on the site, bu I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by http endpoints, but the API does not change that much from version to version as everything is the same as before there, looking at http://docs.geteventstore.com/http-api/3.6.0/

[image]